# writting own array constructor function, assuming array object dosen't exist.. all fine but this.unshift() isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

writting my own array constructor function, assuming array object dosen't exist.. all functions are working as i am expecting but this.unshift() isn't working properly.. when i invoking tostring() after calling unshift() it's giving me unexpected result...

```
function myArray() {
  var i = 0;
  this.length = 0;
  var args = arguments;
  while (args[i] !== undefined) {
    this[i] = args[i];
    this.length++;
    i++;
  }

  this.tostring = function() {
    var result = args[0];
    for (var k = 1; k < args.length; k++) {
      result += "," + args[k];
    }
    return result;
  }

  this.push = function(push) {
    this[args.length] = push;
    args[args.length] = push;
    args.length++;
    return++ this.length;
  }

  this.pop = function() {
    var pres = args[args.length - 1];
    delete args[args.length - 1];
    delete this[args.length - 1];
    args.length--;
    this.length--;
    return pres;
  }

  this.shift = function() {
    var shiftres = args[0];
    var x = 0;
    var y = 1;
    while (args[x] !== undefined) {
      this[x] = args[y];
      args[x] = args[y];
      x++;
      y++;
    }
    this.length--;
    args.length--;
    return shiftres;
  } ** this.unshift ** = function() {
    var args2 = this.unshift.arguments;
    var t = 0;
    var z = 0;
    while (args2[t] !== undefined) {
      this[t] = args2[t];
      args[t] = args2[t];
      t++;
      this.length++;
      args.length++;
    }
    while (args[z] !== undefined) {
      this[t] = args[z];
      args[t] = args[z];
      t++;
      z++;
    }
    return args2;
  }

}
```

Comment: There an error message?

Comment: your unshift isnt an unshift, its rather *override* ...

Comment: and you probably need to rebind arguments to args inside of every function.

Comment: Please edit your question title you misspelled `this.shift()` and omitted letter "f"... xD lol

Comment: any reason you surrounded the call to `unshift()` with **'s ?

Comment: You should not mutate `args`. That should be over after the construction is done. You only must work with `this`. Hint: define all methods on the prototype.

Comment: Using [`unshift.arguments` is deprecated!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jonas_w
figured it out. thank you so much, thanks for your concept, here is my new code for this.unshift()....

```
this.unshift = function() {
var args2 = this.unshift.arguments;
for(var i=this.length-1;i >= 0;i--){
this[i+args2.length]=args[i];
args[i+args2.length]=args[i];
}
for(var i=0;i<args2.length;i++){
this[i]=args2[i];
args[i]=args2[i];
}
this.length=args.length+args2.length;
args.length=args.length+args2.length;
};
```

Comment: Im not shure why you need the args. And if you think my code was helpful you could give an upvote or accept it as answer.

Comment: And the i+1 is unneccessary, its a shortform of i>=0

Answer (score 0):

Im not shure what your unshift should do, but as far i can see it rather overrides. May do this:

```
this.unshift = function(...args) {
 for(var i=this.length-1;i+1;i--){//iterate from last to first
   this[i+args.length]=this[i];//shift args length to the right e.g. one arg [1,2,3] => [1,1,2,3]
}
for(var i=0;i<args.length;i++){
  this[i]=args[i];//copy values into array
}
this.length=this.length+args.length;
};
```

By the way, it would be better to put this into MyArray.prototype.unshift instead of generating new functions at every construction...

http://jsbin.com/lireciqixu/edit?console

Comment: i expecting it to behave like array object unshift() method . i mean when creating an object with using myArray constructor and i call tostring(). it is "1,2,3,"string" something like that but after calling unshift(argument1,argument2,..). tostring will be "argument1,argument2,..,1,2,3 "

Comment: no i have tried but it's not giving the output like i am expecting.. can explain for(var i=this.length-1;i+1;i--) ...... i+1(condition) what it does?

Comment: what will happen to tostring() after calling unshift() based on my code, did you consider that??

Comment: figured it out. thank you so much, thanks for your concept, here is my new code
    this.unshift = function() {
 var args2 = this.unshift.arguments;
  for(var i=this.length-1;i >= 0;i+1,i--){
    this[i+args2.length]=args[i];
 args[i+args2.length]=args[i];
 }
 for(var i=0;i<args2.length;i++){
    this[i]=args2[i];
 args[i]=args2[i];
 }
 this.length=args.length+args2.length;
 args.length=args.length+args2.length;
 };